# Google App Engine Added task goes missing

Tags: google-app-engine, task, task-queue

When I add a task to the task queue, sometimes the task goes missing. I dont get any errors but I just dont find the tasks in my logs. Suppose I add n tasks. The computation cannot go forward without these n tasks finishing. However, I find that one or more of these n tasks just went missing after they were added and my whole algorithm stops in the middle. 
What could be the reason ?
I keep a variable w to check the number of times the task was added. I observe w = n though some tasks were not created.

```
def addtask_whx(index,user,seqlen,vp_compress,iseq_compress):
global w
while True :
    timeout_ms = 100    
    taskq_name = 'whx'+'--'+str(index[0])+'-'+str(index[1])+'-'+str(index[2])+'-'+str(index[3])+'-'+str(index[5]) + '--' + user

    try :

        taskqueue.add(name=taskq_name+str(timeout_ms),queue_name='whx',url='/whx', params={'m': index[0],'n': index[1],'o': index[2],'p': index[3],'q':0,'r':index[5],'user': user,'seqlen':seqlen,'vp':vp_compress,'iseq':iseq_compress})
        w = w+1
        break
    except DeadlineExceededError:
        taskq_name = taskq_name + str(timeout_ms)
        time.sleep(float(timeout_ms)/1000)
        timeout_ms = timeout_ms*4
        logging.error("WHX Task Queue Add Timeout Retrying")
    except TransientError:
        taskq_name = taskq_name + str(timeout_ms)
        time.sleep(float(timeout_ms)/1000)
        timeout_ms = timeout_ms*4
        logging.error("WHX Task Queue Add Transient Error Retrying")
    except TombstonedTaskError:
        logging.error("WHX Task Queue Tombstoned Error")
        break
```

Comment: You might want to post some of your Task code. This obviously shouldn't be happening, so either your Task is completing earlier than you expect without throwing an exception or you have found a Bug

Comment: Usually when people say a task isn't executing, it actually is - it's just not logging anything, and they're only looking at the logs at 'info' level or above. Are you sure that's not the case here? Have you set the log viewer to 'all requests'?

Comment: I did check the logs with "all requests". I find some tasks missing. Moreover I write a datastore entity when each task finishes and I do find the number of datastore entities less than n sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** this is not the answer you're looking for, but I hope it will help you nonetheless.

> The computation cannot go forward
>   without these n tasks finishing

It sounds like you are using the task queue for something it was not designed to do. You should read: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html#Queue_Concepts

Tasks are not guaranteed to be executed in the order they arrive, and they are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once. In some cases, a single task may be executed *more than once or not at all*. Further, a task can be cancelled and re-queued at the discretion of the App Engine based on available resources. For example, your `timeout_ms = 100` is very low; if a new JVM has to be started, which could take several seconds, tasks n+1 and n+2 may be executed before task n.

In short, the task queue is not a reliable mechanism for performing strictly sequential computation. You've been warned.

-tjw